# Does SOAP request and response travel as serialized object over HTTP

Tags: java, http, rest, serialization, soap

I was trying to find out why SOAp is heavier than REST.? Does SOAP request and response always travel as serialized objects over HTTP.

Is there any serialization concept involved in REST during transport?

In the service, even though we sent Object, REST framework will convert into the format which we tell in @Produces before goint to HTTP?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "serialized objects over HTTP." Messaging by its very nature involves serialization of some sort, be it memory-to-XML serialization, memory-to-JSON serialization, or memory-to-base64-encoded-bytes serialization. So both REST and SOAP involve some kind of serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why SOAP is considered heavier than REST is two fold. SOAP requires an extensive XML envelope to house all the parameters where a REST service generally takes parameters via the query string or a regular HTTP post.

Additionally, the response from REST services is generally (although not always) JSON. SOAP services respond in XML which is very wordy. It seems the general consensus on why SOAP is more heavyweight is due to the additional data traveling over the wire in the form of XML tags.

Comment: How about serialization, deserialization? Does REST all sending serialized objects? or in server itself, it is converted into JSON or XML whichever format specified.?

Comment: REST/SOAP is basically just a transport layer. Once it gets to the server, it's really going to be implementation dependent on what the deserialized form is going to be. JSON tends to be smaller than XML when it's going across the wire because XML is "self-describing" which means you have a lot of additional data (i.e. tags).